# Using <p-dropdown> with form control

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I think I am having an issue with value binding. I have 2 dropdowns on my page currently. The rest of the page is using PrimeNg for UI and would like to make these dropdowns look the same as the rest of the page. How should I go about making this work.

One dropdown is a supervisor list.

```html
<div class="ui-g form-group">
  <label for="supervisors">Supervisors * </label>
  <select 
    class="form-control"
    id="supervisors" 
    required
    [(ngModel)]="model.supervisor"
    name="supervisor"
  >
    <option *ngFor="let sup of supervisors" [value]="sup">
      {{sup}}
    </option>
    <div
      [hidden]="supervisors.valid || supervisors.pristine"
      class="alert alert-danger"
    >
      Supervisor is required
    </div>
  </select>
</div>
```

The other is a leave code list

```html
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-1" id="test">
   <label for="codes">Leave Codes * </label>
   <select 
     class="form-control"
     id="codes"
     placeholder="Select Leave Code *"
     required 
     [(ngModel)]="model.code" 
     name="code"
    >
      <option *ngFor="let cod of codes" [value]="cod">{{cod}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have 2 arrays of values being called from my .ts file

```js
supervisors = ['Alex',"Jones",'Joe','Rogan'];
codes = ['Personal Leave','Vacation Leave', 'Sick Leave'];
```

When I use the  tags I just get an empty drop down. I tried just using  initially but then I was not able to get the required fields to validate.

Comment: where are you using p-dropdown ??

Comment: @DirtyMind I am not in that code snippet. But when I try in VSCode, it does not work properly. I am trying to ask what would be the best way to use p-dropdown in this scenario!

Comment: You mean you tried p-dropdown and that is not working right ? Also are you using the same supervisors and codes array in p-dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import DropdownModule?

```
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
```

See the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown), html binding should be

```
<p-dropdown [options]="supervisorList" [(ngModel)]="supervisor"></p-dropdown>
```

where `supervisorList` will be defined as `SelectItem` in controller and needs to be in a label + value format.

```
supervisorList: SelectItem[];
this.supervisorList= [
            {label: 'Alex', value: 'Alex'},
            ...
];
```